# How to set the Language of my App, to not show EN but DE in App Store?

Tags: react-native, app-store, app-store-connect

We are publishing our App in AppStore for Apple and Android. In AppStore Screen our App is signed as language "EN" not DE. Is there any way in React-Native to set this to DE?

All answers I found so far was about multilanguage, that is not what we need.'

Thanks.